# Create alias for background color

Tags: powershell

Is there a way that I can set `$Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor` to an alias so that I don't have to type the whole thing out every time?

Comment: `$alias = $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function bgc { param($color); $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = $color }

C:\PS> bgc 'Red'
```

Add function to your PSProfile

Comment: And for those that want tab completion (or a pop-up list in ISE) you can do `function bgc { param([System.ConsoleColor]$color){...`

Comment: Thank you so much. FYI I added a `Clear-Host` to the end of you function.